# Managing Dupuytren's Contracture

Tags: piano, physical-limitations

I am a pianist grappling w/ increasingly problematic Dupuytren's Contracture.   Range of motion of pinkie on right hand is constrained both in reaching beyond a 7th and in terms of general dexterity.  But finger is not yet permanently "curled."

Fasciectomy seems way premature. Hand specialist questions whether he could get the leverage to effectively break the cords after Xiaflex treatment.  He raises third alternative:  surgical incision to clip the cords.

All answers/experiences welcome!

Comment: I don't think any of us are qualified to give medical advice and, in any case, diagnosing and prescribing over the internet and not ethical practices in most countries.

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because we cannot answer medical questions. However, questions about how to manage specific musical passages given a physical limitation are very much within the scope of this site.